# Sequential animations in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I need to perform some sequential animations on the same object. I used the callback function of the first animation to call the second one. I have a loop in which a node is retrieved at a time from a list of nodes. The problem is it always returns the attributes of last node.

Here is my piece of code:

```
 for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
     var node = nodes[i];
    obj.animate({y:node.getY()}, 500, function(){  
    this.animate({height:node.getHeight()}, 500);  
            })
  }
```

My question is how should I write this piece of code to solve the problem?

Comment: What does your HTML look like and how are you declaring the var nodes?

Comment: the var nodes are declared globally.

Comment: Ok i meant to ask what does it contain?

Comment: it is an array of Node objects. each Node object has a set of properties